# closed open real analysis proof

Tags: real-analysis

here is the question

- Let $K$ be a closed subset of $\Bbb R$ and let $\{p_n\}$ be a
  sequence in $K$ which converges to $p\in \Bbb R$. Prove that $p\in
     K$.

if $K$ is closed subset and $\{p_n\}$ is sequence in $K$, every point of $\{p_n\}$ should be included inside of the $K$, because $K$ is closed and every points should be an interior point of $K$, 
therefore $\{p_n\}$ convergence point should be an interior point of $K$. 
( Is this ok to prove for this question? or some part does not right?)

- Show by example that the conclusion is false if $K$ is not closed.

um.. example. $(a,a_1,a_2,a_3]$. This subset is not closed. and by definition if k is not a closed set any subsequence is not guaranteed to be an every interior point. so subsequence could be converge to a3+ϵ and this point is not an interior point of k.

this concept is very hard to understand...

Comment: Every point is an interior point if and only if the set is open.

Comment: I'm confused about K and F. You haven't defined F.

Comment: What does the notation $(a,a_1,a_2,a_3]$ mean?

Comment: oh F is K typo.

Comment: and it said show example so just define any example

Comment: Tip: Try to use proper [TeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8271)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** (I'll assume $F$ is a typo and you mean $K$) Your first argument isn't correct since $K$ is closed, not open; in particular, not every point needs to be an interior point. Try to show that $p$ is a limit point of $K$, then use the fact that $K$ is closed to conclude that $p\in K$.

For the second argument, think of specific intervals (it seems like you *might* have the right idea, but you haven't explained it clearly).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose by contradiction that $p \notin K$ that is $p \in K^c$. Since $K$ is closed, $K^c$ is open. Hence $p$ is an interior point of $K^c$, and there is a neighborhood of $p$ included in $K^c$ (definition of interior point). No point of the sequence is in this neighborhood (since every $p_n$ is in $K$), contradicting convergence to $p$.

Example: consider the set $(0,2)$ and the sequence $p_n=\frac{1}{n}$. To what point does it converge?

Comment: oh I see. pn it can prove with contradiction. and pn converge to 0 but closed point (0,2) does not include the point. thank you user70645,i want to give u reputation but my reputation is not over 15 lol

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i read the wrong definition.

By the definition K is closed set mean k^c is an open set.

open set should include all the interior points.

so can you say k^c is an open set and  {pn}^c is also open set

so k^c should include all the interior point  and also {pn}'s convergence point.

Im not sure this argument is valid.